# Null character in the end of the new dynamic char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, null-terminated

If I create dynamic char array:

```
 char * c = new char[5];
```

and I DON'T fiil it with string, will the null character `\0` be in the end of this array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, char pointers are just pointers. They don't even have to point to arrays.

In your specific case, the elements of the newed array are left uninitialized. If you want them to be zero initialized you can do this:

```
char * c = new char[5]();
```

This will set all the elements to `\0`. You could consider `c` to point to a null-terminated string.